# Cannot switch profile on Bluetooth headphones

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, bluetooth, headphones, mono

I've just switched to ubuntu 15.10 and I encountered a quite annoying bug. 
When I connect the headset (Betron BT1050) to the laptop, it connects only as a mono device, when I try to switch the profile it doesn't on Blueman and Pulse audio (pulse audio changes it, but no effect it auto resets to HFP) it says it is not possible. Said all that, I must tell that I had it work properly two times, both after changing some things at the `audio.conf` file, but after disconnect and reconnect it connected again to mono device. 
My `audio.conf` file looks like this and I this is what I found online ( when I first opened it, there was nothing):

`       # Configuration file for the audio service

```
   # This section contains options which are not specific to any
   # particular interface

   [General]

   Disable=Headset (according to a guy online this way the device will connect as a A2DP and first time it worked)


  # Switch to master role for incoming connections (defaults to true)
  #Master=true

     # If we want to disable support for specific services
     # Defaults to supporting all implemented services
     #Disable=Gateway,Source,Socket
     Enable=Gateway,Source
     Enable=Source,Sink,Headset,Gateway,Control,Media
     Disable=Socket

    # SCO routing. Either PCM or HCI (in which case audio is routed   to/from ALSA)
    # Defaults to HCI
    #SCORouting=PCM

    # Automatically connect both A2DP and HFP/HSP profiles for incoming
   # connections. Some headsets that support both profiles will only connect the
  # other one automatically so the default setting of true is usually a good
  # idea.
  AutoConnect=True

  # Headset interface specific options (i.e. options which affect how the audio

  # service interacts with remote headset devices)
  [Headset]


  # Set to true to support HFP, false means only HSP is supported
  # Defaults to true
    HFP=false

    # Maximum number of connected HSP/HFP devices per adapter.        Defaults to 1
   MaxConnected=1

   # Set to true to enable use of fast connectable mode (faster page scanning)
   # for HFP when incoming call starts. Default settings are restored after
    # call is answered or rejected. Page scan interval is much shorter and page
   # scan type changed to interlaced. Such allows faster connection initiated
   # by a headset.
    FastConnectable=false

   # Just an example of potential config options for the other interfaces
    [A2DP]
    SBCSources=1
    MPEG12Sources=0
```

I know many people experience it and some might have a solution. Do you have any ideas of a workaround?

Thanks